# Firefox addon sdk tab script talk to page mod script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In `main.js` I am opening a tab and attaching a script with `page-mod`. The html file that is being opened it has a bunch of regular  includes.

Sort of have two issues.

1. The script from page mod does not get attached until after those other scripts are loaded, and also
2. the regular scripts can't access variables defined in the script that is attached with page mod.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send messages.

**Directly**

In your page-mod, send a message:

*page-mod.js*

```
window.postMessage(projectUniqueId + '|' + message, domain);
```

If your page needs to work with all domains (being a plug-in), you might need '*' as a domain.

*tab-attach.js*

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event){
  var words = event.data.split('|');
  if (words[0] == projectUniqueId){
    handle(words[1]);
  }          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The script from page mod does not get attached until after those other scripts are loaded,

Specifying [`contentScriptWhen: 'ready'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Constructors) in the page-mod constructor should "[l]oad content scripts once DOM content has been loaded, corresponding to the DOMContentLoaded event"

> the regular scripts can't access variables defined in the script that is attached with page mod.

Have a look at [Expose objects to page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Expose_objects_to_page_scripts). You need to use

> ```
> var contentScriptObject = {"greeting" : "hello from add-on"};
>
> unsafeWindow.clonedContentScriptObject = cloneInto(contentScriptObject, unsafeWindow);
> ```

in the content script to make the object accessible.